# Fixed body height on page, CSS seems to be fine

Tags: html, css, height

The [portfolio page](http://scotthsmith.com/portfolio/) on my site, appears to have a body element that is stuck at around 86 pixels or so in height. I have searched through the HTML and CSS to see what may be the issue and came up empty-handed. Nothing appears to be setting the height of the body, although elements display fine outside of it. I would rather not use body `{height: 100%;}`. Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: Good idea, I tried that, but to no avail. This hasn't caused a problem on any of my other pages.

Comment: Wait, you want to make the body height 100%, but you don't want to use `body {height:100%}`? Why is that?

Comment: Adding a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) class to the `#items`, it seems to be working on live editing the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `<HTML>` or `</HEAD>` tags at the top

EDIT: Theres something wrong with that `doctype` you got up there too.. Removing that seems to fix your issue.

Comment: LOL, I missed that, while inspecting :P

Comment: When I removed the `doctype` up top, it seems to fix the issue. The syntax looks correct though :?

Comment: There's something funky going on with the way you're setting up your template. Adding `overflow:auto;` to `#container` fixes it as well

Comment: Removing the Doctype, gets the browser to decide what to do with the page, it is usually a *BAD* idea to remove the `DOCTYPE`, I'm pretty sure it has to be the missing tags that  is causing the problem.

Comment: @RCorrie Those tags are formally optional, so leaving them out is not a problem for the browsers. (Not saying that I'd ever recommend doing that, just that it can't cause any issues.)

Comment: I agree on the doctype thing, just worth mentioning. Well I copied his code over to my local server and fixing the errors with the tags doesn't help, just like Mr Lister pointed out.

Comment: @PranavKapoor Correct. Leaving out the doctype triggers quirks mode, and different browsers have different quirks. Goodbye browser-interoperability.

Comment: You are right, removing the `DOCTYPE` worked, but the syntax was correct... adding `overflow: auto;` to `#container` worked just fine, even with the `DOCTYPE`. Thanks guys!